# A network related or instance specific error In SQL Server Compact

Tags: sql-server-ce, connection-string

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server Compact Edition in it. I use the following connection string (database doesn't have password)

```
"Data Source = " + (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\db.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;");
```

but when I open connection, I got above error

TIA

Comment: Are you using a SqlCeConnection object (which you should), or a SqlConnection object (wrong) ?

Comment: oh the problem was here thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use SQL Server Compact via ADO.NET, use the **SqlCeConnection** object, not the SqlConnection object.